# Javascript working in console, not working (propertly) as userscript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

This is my first post on this forum.
On various forums there are links to t.me/, by default they look like this `https://t.me/netflix/3724` , a preview of one post opens, when you click on CONTEXT you go straight to the feed, and this does a little code do - adds "s" between two slashes, reload the page, and redirect straight to the feed,   and adress looks like: `https://t.me/s/netflix/3724`
Code work fine only in browser console, but not as a userscript- then the page reloads and redirects to telegram.org.
I want the code to work as userscript.
Here's what it userscript looks like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Telegram Direct 
// @namespace       Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match           https://t.me/*
// @version         1.0
// @run-at          document-start
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

window.location.href = "https://t.me/s" + window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.indexOf('s', 1));
```

I'm not a programmer, I've tried many solutions from this site, but since I don't really know what to look for, I ask for help.

Greets.

Comment: window.location.href = "https://t.me/s" + window.location.pathname;

Comment: This doesn't work, the code copies the address in a loop and this breaks the connection. In the console it doesn't work either, it doesn't replace the address but pastes a new one and it looks like this:`https://t.me/netflix/t.me/s/netflix/3724`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in a different way :) The solution below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Telegram Direct 
// @namespace       Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match           https://t.me/*
// @version         Over 9000
// @author          Ukash
// @run-at          document-start
// @noframes
// @icon            https://telegram.org/img/favicon.ico
// @description     Telegram Direct
// ==/UserScript==


document.querySelector('.tgme_page_context_link').click();
```